# Binding list<string> in columns of datagrid with caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, list, caliburn.micro, datagridcolumn

My class is this :

```
public class Articolo : Screen
{
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost{ get; set; }
        public decimal Price{ get; set; }
        public List<Ean> BarCode { get; set; }
}
```

and this Ean Class:

```
public class Ean
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
}
```

My datagrid is :

```
<DataGrid Height="367" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="14,52,12,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="List" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Codice" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description }" Header="Descrizione" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}" Header="Quantita" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Prezzo" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BarCode}" Header="BarCodes" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

He is a part of ViewModel:

```
    [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class BolleViewModel : Screen
    {
        public List<Articolo> List { get; private set; }

        public BViewModel()
        {
            Recover recover = new Recover();
            List = recover.Import();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("List");
        }
    }
```

In the columns BarCodes is write (Collection)! And not the barcodes.
Why? How can I view the list of barcodes in the column? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BarCode` is a `List<T>` and the `ToString()` method of `List<T>` does not by itself display the contents of the list.

The easiest thing you can do is probably to implement an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and apply this converter in your `BarCode` binding.

As a start, the converter could look something like this:

```
public class EanListToStringConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                         object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return String.Join(" ", ((List<Ean>)value).Select(ean => ean.Code));
   }
   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                             object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return NotSupportedException();
   }
}
```

Then, you need to add a converter instance as a resource in your view:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <converters:EanListToStringConverter x:Key="EanListToString"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And finally in your `BarCode` binding invoke this instance, something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BarCode, 
    Converter={StaticResource EanListToString}}" Header="BarCodes" />
```